# Ubuntu Mate : Android Studio - Gradle project sync failed

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, gradle

i am new to android studio.
while creating my first android  application.
its shows some errors..

```
Gradle sync started 11:00:29 AM Gradle sync failed: Process 'command '/home/db2admin/Downloads/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
        Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

my java version is

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

please help me to fix this error.

**gradle-wrapper.properties contains**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/g​radle-1.10-all.zip
```

**app/build.gradle contaions**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.db2admin.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: 1) `Consult IDE log for more details` 2) Show your full Gradle file please

Comment: gradle-wrapper.properties#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip

Comment: gradle.properties contains  org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: build.gradle contains                                                              
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: paste the content of build.gradle file here

Comment: @AshishRawat buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: hey buddy... have you set path for your jdk?

Comment: Please do not use the comments for code. Anyways, your Gradle version is super out-dated. `distributionUrl` probably should be `2.10`, not `1.10`

Comment: @Swanand i think it's /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Comment: Where r the dependencies.. i only see blank dependencies.. there should be a gradle file that contain all the dependencies

Comment: @AshishRawat   dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

Comment: Are you behind any proxy ? how did you create the project. as your gradle version is very old ? Doesn't your android studio ask for an option for upgrade ? What is android studio version ?

Comment: version - android studio 2.2

Answer (score 0):

From [Gradle Plugin Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)

> Android Plugin for Gradle, Revision 2.2.0 (September 2016)
>
> Dependencies:
>
> - Gradle 2.14.1 or higher.
> - Build Tools 23.0.2 or higher.

Firstly, in your `gradle.properties`, this isn't "2.14.1 or higher"

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/g​radle-1.10-all.zip
```

Secondly, check your `buildToolsVersion` in the other `build.gradle` file

Then, your error message points at `Process 'command '/home/db2admin/Downloads/android-studio/jre/bin/java''`, which means you are using the Android Studio bundled Java JRE, rather than a system installed JDK, if you have one. You may need to go into the IDE settings and change that to the correct Java SDK.

Comment: distributionUrl changed to this .distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip. but issue still remain

Comment: What Android version are you trying to compile? Android < 24 doesn't support Java 8... Although, you are using `android-studio/jre/bin/java` rather than your system installed Java

Comment: compile sdk version is android 24

Comment: build tool version is 24.0.3

Comment: Can you please add the `app/build.gradle` file to your question?

Comment: app/build.gradle added

Comment: That looks like the root `build.gradle`... If you've created a blank Android Studio project, you should have a "top-level" `build.gradle`, `settings.gradle`, then an `app` folder with its own `build.gradle`

Comment: am updated the question with actual app/build.gradle

Comment: Hmm... Looks pretty standard... I think you should click the "Show Log" link of `Consult IDE log for more details`, but maybe after you point the IDE Java SDK to your system install Java JDK